# Oracle sql : How to use regexp_* , to take tokens to two or more columns

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

How do I use oracle regexp_*str to split streetnum if it is present? Objective is to make a view V_MY_USERS that has 3 columns ID, STREET_NUM, STREET_NAME.

```
MY_USERS - that has two columns

ID    STREET_ADDRESS
-------------------- 
1     991 My Street  # Some records start with street number followed by space
2     Don street     # some records do not have street num, => null
```

To create a View: V_MY_USERS that has 3 columns

```
ID    STREET_NUM       STREET_NAME
----------------------------------
1     991              My Street            
2     null             Don street
```

Comment: What about an address like 99A Celal Bayar Blv.?

Comment: @mathguy, From below answer ... REGEXP_SUBSTR(STREET_ADDRESS, '^\w+') as STREET_NUM , would work for " 99A Celal Bayar Blv"

Comment: That would pull Don as street number in your second example.

Comment: REGEXP_SUBSTR(STREET_ADDRESS, '^\d\w+') AS STREET_NUM,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` and `REGEXP_REPLACE` here:

```sql
CREATE VIEW V_MY_USERS AS
SELECT
    ID,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(STREET_ADDRESS, '^\d+') AS STREET_NUM,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(STREET_ADDRESS, '^\d+ ', '') AS STREET_NAME
FROM MY_USERS
ORDER BY ID;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: Sorry, the second one is a view (just a query), updated my question. So there is no update statement.

Comment: @Espresso Reload your page.

Comment: great thanks. I didn't know I can use an online oracle simulator :). View query works perfectly. Thanks again.

Comment: Does dbfiddle allow testing V_MY_USERS?

Comment: @Espresso Not sure if creating views is possible, but you shouldn't need to do this, since a view just wraps some underlying select query.  Updates are another story...you should really test.  DBFiddle does allow testing updates, but I usually don't bother.